# `git add -u` on JetBrains IDEs

Tags: git, version-control, pycharm

I am currently using PyCharm and there seems to be no option for `git add -u`. I also do not see explicit commands that affect git index. Is this because I did not look hard enough? Or does PyCharm and other JetBrains IDEs shy away from it and rely more on the local history, which is pretty powerful itself?

Comment: Did you see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63391 and linked issues?

Comment: No and now I know an extra place to look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not exist yet. You're going to have to go into your directory using CMD or Terminal and then use git to do what you need it to do. Those changes however, will show up in PyCharm